# Affine subspace convexity

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I'm trying to show by induction that if we have for all $x, y \in A \subset X, $ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ the following
$tx+(1-t)y \in A $ then $A$ is an affine subspace.

I'm struggling on what to do for the inductive step. I need to show that if $\sum _i t_i =1  $ then $\sum_i t_ix_i \in A$ for $x_i \in A$. Any pointers?

Comment: That is how I define an affine subspace. How do you define it?

Comment: Subset $A \subset X$ such that $\sum_i t_ix_i \in A$ when $x_i \in A, \sum _i t_i =1.$

Comment: Show that if it is true for $n$ points $a_1,...,a_n$ then it is true for $n+1$ points.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Clearly it is true for one or two points.

Suppose it is true for $n$ points, that is if $a_i \in A$  and $\sum_{k=1}^n t_k=1$ then $\sum_{k=1}^n t_ka_k \in A$.

Pick some other point $a_{n+1}$. And suppose $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} s_k=1$. We can assume that none of the $s_k$ are zero or one otherwise it is true by the inductive hypothesis.

Then note that
$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} s_k a_k = \sum_{k=1}^{n} s_k a_k + s_{n+1}a_{n+1} = (1-s_{n+1})  \sum_{i=1}^{n} {1 \over \sum_{k=1}^{n} s_i }s_k a_k + s_{n+1}a_{n+1}$.